# Start an async background daemon in a Python FastAPI app

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, fastapi

I'm building an async backend for an analytics system using FastAPI. The thing is it has to: a) listen for API calls and be available at all times; b) periodically perform a data-gathering task (parsing data and saving it into the DB).

I wrote this function to act as a daemon:

```
    async def start_metering_daemon(self) -> None:
        """sets a never ending task for metering"""
        while True:
            delay: int = self._get_delay()  # delay in seconds until next execution
            await asyncio.sleep(delay)
            await self.gather_meterings()  # perfom data gathering
```

What I'm trying to achieve is so that when app starts it also adds this daemon function into the main event loop and execute it when it has time. However, I haven't been able to find a suitable solution which is adequate to the scale of the task (adding Celery and similar stuff is an overkill).

I have tried following ways to achieve this but none of them worked:

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event() -> None:
    """tasks to do at server startup"""
    await Gatherer().start_metering_daemon()
```

Result: server can't start up since the thread is blocked

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event() -> None:
    """tasks to do at server startup"""
    fastapi.BackgroundTasks().add_task(Gatherer().start_metering_daemon)
```

Result: task is never executed as observed in logs

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event() -> None:
    """tasks to do at server startup"""
    fastapi.BackgroundTasks().add_task(asyncio.run, Gatherer().start_metering_daemon())
```

Result: same as previous one

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event() -> None:
    """tasks to do at server startup"""
    threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(Gatherer().start_metering_daemon(),)).start()
```

Result: this one works but a) makes no sence; b) spawns N identical threads for N Uvicorn workers which all write same data N times into the DB.

I am out of solutions by now. I am pretty sure there must be a solution to my problem since is looks pretty trivial to me but I couldn't find one.

If you want more context here is the [repo](https://github.com/arseniiarsenii/mastodon-meter) of the project I reffer to.

Comment: If run the task every a given time is a option for you, you can try `rq`. While you need to install redis and the main objective of the library is work with queues, here there are examples of scheduling tasks:  https://python-rq.org/docs/scheduling/

Comment: can someone explain why background task solution doesn’t work but async io create task does ?

Comment: @toing from Starlette docs: "A background task should be attached to a response, and will run only once the response has been sent" so If there is no http request-response Background task won't run.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? Can we access the worker id somehow, and stop the tasks prematurely on all but one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event() -> None:
    """tasks to do at server startup"""
    asyncio.create_task(Gatherer().start_metering_daemon())
```

Comment: This is not working :( when you have other async operations within that function, it still throws: [2021-09-10 21:00:56 +0000] [1330] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:1337)
[2021-09-10 21:00:56 +0000] [1330] [WARNING] Worker with pid 1337 was terminated due to signal 6